# How to make Button in table responsive using angular material table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material

I need to make my button responsive inside a table. 
This is what it looks like in my desktop and mobile view respectively:

**Desktop View**

[image]

**Mobile View**

[image]

As you can see, in the mobile view, the delete button is partially covered already.

This is how it is coded in my html

```
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="design-header">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
            </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="design-container mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="billTypeList">

            <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort style="width: 100%">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="BillName">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.BillName}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="ConsumptionAbbr">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Abbreviation </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.ConsumptionAbbr}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="DateAdded">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date Added </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.PostingDateTime | date}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Delete </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color">
                        <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteBillType(row.BillTypeID)">Delete</button>
                    </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
                </mat-row>
            </mat-table>

            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Can you please show me how to do this right? 

**UPDATE**
This did not work too.
<div class="table-reponsive">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="MonthNo">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Month </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.MonthNo}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="RatePerSqm">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Rate Per Sq. M. </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.RatePerSqm}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="FixedAmount">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fixed Amount </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.FixedAmount | currency: 'PHP '}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="EffectiveDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Effective Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.EffectiveDateTime | date}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteRealPropertyTaxRate(row.RealPropertyTaxRateID)">Delete Record</button>
        <button  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEdit(row)">Edit Record</button>
        <!-- <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
            <mat-icon>more_horiz</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="onEdit(row)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            <span>Edit</span>
            </button>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="deleteRealPropertyTaxRate(row.RealPropertyTaxRateID)">
            <mat-icon>delete_sweep</mat-icon>
            <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
        </mat-menu> -->
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

Using the class table responsive did not do the  trick.

Comment: Can you create a [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) example so we could try to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate your scenario in the following table. Key is to use"table-responsive" class from Bootstrap.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th> Actions </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>November 14, 2012</td>
      <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>November 14, 2012</td>
      <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>November 14, 2012</td>
      <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for that but I cannot use the "table" tag in my "mat-table" since it will cause an error if I am using angular material 5. I need to have angular material 6 for that to work. I tried using @media in my css but it doesn't seem to work also..

Comment: I have no idea about angular-material, but the key is "class : table-responsive", which is css (class of bootstrap3). Can you try adding that on "mat-table" element?

Comment: I will look into that. That table class should actually do the trick but again that's my dilemma if I use the table tag. Thank you!

Comment: I will look into that. That table class should actually do the trick but again that's my dilemma if I use the table tag. Thank you!

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Does the solution above solve your problem?

Comment: I couldn't make the table tag run on with mat-table so it really didn't solve my issue. So I just voted up.

Comment: I suppose I haven't made myself clear...I will try again, I suggest you to use class "table-responsive" on mat-table..( "<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort style="width: 100%" class="table-responsive">")...Can you try that?

Comment: Please see the update I made above. I still didn't get the result I wanted. I just created and alternative way of doing it and it is the ones that are commented. Thank you.